# Rewrite URL in XAMPP VirtualHost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

Been trying to play with mod_rewrite through `.htaccess` in one Xampp virtualhost, but I am not getting the results that I am looking for.

What I am tring to do is to rewrite the following: `www.example.com/name/billy.html` to: `www.example.com/billy`

Without trying to rewrite the URLs the virtualhost is working fine, I have access to all pages. However, when I add the `.htaccess` with the corresponding rewrite rule I get a 404 page not found. The regex is working as expected though. I see that the request to `www.example.com/name/billy.html` it's been rewritten to `www.example.com/billy`, but the page doesn't load.

The `name` folder exists in the file structure and the `.htaccess` is inside the `example` folder.

Currently, my vh configuration looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/example"
  ServerName www.example.com
  <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/example">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is the content of the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^name\/([a-z]+).html$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

What is missing?

Comment: Are you sure the file `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/hello/billy` does exist?

Comment: The /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/hello/billy doesn’t exist. But the /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/hello/billy.html yes. Like I said without the url rewriting everything is working fine. Is when I try do rewrite to  www.hello.com/billy I get the 404 page not found.

Comment: _Aside:_ "Rewrite URL in XAMPP VirtualHost" - this title is a little misleading since you aren't actually rewriting the URL in the VirtualHost, you are using `.htaccess`.

Comment: www.hello.com/billy doesn't exist so it must be www.hello.com/billy.html. Change the regex to: `^name\/([a-z]+.html)$` and it will work. I've moved the closing bracket after `.html`.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am tring to do is to rewrite the following: `www.example.com/name/billy.html` to: `www.example.com/billy`

You seem to have the process the wrong way round and possibly mixing up "rewrites" and "redirects"?

You should be *internally rewriting* from the visible "friendly" URL to the underlying file-path that actually handles the request. You are trying to do the opposite here. How is your system expected to handle a request for `/billy`? (It doesn't, and generates a 404.)

You may be thinking you can *change* the URL using `.htaccess` (mod_rewrite) alone? But no, that is not how this works.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^name\/([a-z]+).html$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
> ```

You mention "rewrite", but this directive is in fact a "redirect" (as indicated by the `R` flag). Specifically, a 302 (temporary) redirect in this instance.

(You might actually want to implement a redirect like this, if you are changing an existing URL structure, but more on that later<sup>***1**</sup>)

A URL "rewrite" is entirely internal to the server. The user only sees the public URL, they do not see the URL that it might be rewritten to. You (the user) can't "see" a rewrite.

A "redirect" on the other hand, usually refers to an *external redirect*, ie. a 3xx response sent back to the client with an instruction to make a new request to a different URL. The URL being redirected to is visible to the user. This is used when content has moved to a different URL.

So, following your example, you should be requesting/linking to (in your HTML source) the short/friendly URL `/billy` and internally rewriting the request to `/name/billy.html` that actually handles the request.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite from "billy" to "name/billy.html"
RewriteRule ^[a-z]+$ name/$0.html [NC,L]
```

The `$0` backreference contains the entire URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Only use the NC flag if you do need to match uppercase letters as well. But a request for `/Billy` won't serve `/name/billy.html` on a case-sensitive OS.

And that's really it, with regards to the URL-rewritting, you can stop reading here.

---

#### <sup>***1**</sup> Redirect from old to new

Regarding the external "redirect" mentioned above. You might choose to implement a redirect (in the opposite direction) if you are changing an existing URL structure and the old URLs have been indexed by search engines and/or linked (or bookmarked) to by external third parties - in order to preserve SEO and keep users happy.

For example, say your original URLs were of the form `/name/billy.html` and you later decided to change your URLs to `/billy` instead. You first change the URLs in the HTML source and implement the "rewrite" as mentioned above so the new URLs now work. You then might implement an external redirect from the old `/name/billy.html` URL to the new `/billy` URL.

For this, you would use a directive like you had initially, except you have to be careful of redirect-loops because you are already rewriting the request in the opposite directive. You only want to redirect "direct/initial" requests and not rewritten requests by the earlier rewrite (that is actually later in the file). An easy way to check for "direct" requests is to check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable, which is empty on the initial request and set to `200` (as in 200 OK status) when the request is rewritten.

For example, the following "redirect" would go *before* the above "rewrite", immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive:

```
# Redirect from "name/billy.html" to "/billy"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^name/([a-z]+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

This should ultimately be a 301 (permanent) redirect since the URL has presumably changed *permanently*. However, always test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

---

Further reading:

- [Reference: mod_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)